# how to capture the canvas drawn signature without background

Tags: ios, canvas, drawrect

```
I know this question is already asked but i am not getting my solution.
This is the link i am using for drawing  signature
```

https://github.com/oflannabhra/Paint-App/tree/master/Classes

for saving image i am using

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Want to capture signature with transparent background.But white background is also displaying,for transparent background i am writing

```
self.canvasView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.canvasView.opaque=NO;
imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Please help.